# currying requests angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have three forms in the same container, all the actions use a objectId, so i wanna apply the objectId and send a function.
Obs: unfortunately i need to use ES5.

```
var doRequest = function(someId){
        return function(reqFunction){
                return reqFunction(someId);
        };
    };
  var partial = doRequest("mongoId");

  var getRequest  = partial(function(){

  });

  var postRequest =  partial(function(){

  });

 controllerAlias.getRequest = getRequest;
 controllerAlias.postRequest = postRequest;
```

Comment: Is what you wrote not working?

Comment: Javascript does not understand the reqfunction as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curry is working, maybe is just missing one **return function** to do the proper assignations. Please check:

```js
var doRequest = function(someId){
        return function(reqFunction){
                return reqFunction(someId);
        };
    };
  var partial = doRequest("mongoId");

  var getRequest  = partial(function(id){
   return function(){console.log('in getRequest: ' + id)};
  });

  var postRequest =  partial(function(id){
  return function(){console.log('in postRequest: ' + id)};
  });
  
  const controllerAlias = {};
  controllerAlias.getRequest = getRequest;
  controllerAlias.postRequest = postRequest;
  
  controllerAlias.getRequest();
  controllerAlias.postRequest();
```